# Users with 'Read' access not able to like posts on newsfeed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, newsfeed, like, read

We have a NewsFeed WebPart added to our site collection. But users with read access are not able to like the post.

Generally users with read access should be able to like the posts because on our other site collection, users with read access are able to like the posts.

I have checked the permissions, users have read permission on the site collections as well as on MicroFeed list but yet 'Like' option isn't coming for them at all on this particular site collection but if they have read access on any other site collection then the 'Like' option is coming.

Any insights why it is happening ?

Comment: Compare the permissions granted to the Read permission, if you have customized the permissions this can happen

Comment: Compared the permissions granted to the Read permission. It's same on both the site collection.